# Adding CommandParameter when associating MVVM-Light RelayCommand<T> to button breaks CanExecute

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I am not sure if this is an MVVM-Light bug or just something that doesn't work in WPF.... I have a button where I am setting the Command property to a RelayCommand.  Everything works fine as long as I don't set the CommandParameter property.  Once I do, the CanExecute callback quits working.

I am using the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf namespace as I am working in .Net 4.5.2.  Here is a code snippit:

```
    public RelayCommand<IList> SetFlagCommand { get; private set; }
    ...
    SetFlagCommand = new RelayCommand<IList>(SetFlag, CanSetFlag);
    ...
     mButtons.Add(new Button
        {
            ...
            Command = SetFlagCommand,
            CommandParameter = new Binding("SelectedItems") { ElementName = "lstAllChoices" },
            });

    ...
    private void SetFlag(IList list)...
    private bool CanSetFlag(IList list)...
```

The CanSetFlag method is called once, but then never again.  If I don't set the CommandParameter property, it works as expected.  Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to set the `CommandParameter` property to a `Binding`. Bind it using the `BindingOperations.SetBinding` method instead:

```
Button button = new Button()
{
    Command = SetFlagCommand
};
BindingOperations.SetBinding(button, Button.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("SelectedItems") { ElementName = "lstAllChoices" });

mButtons.Add(btn);
```

Also make sure that the type of the source property (`SelectedItems`) matches the type parameter `T` of the `RelayCommand<T>`.

Comment: OK, that fixed the CanExecute not being called problem.  Now my problem is that this is being done from the viewmodel and it can't find the source for the binding.

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=lstAllChoices'...

Comment: I should clarify one thing.... the button is being added to an ItemsControl on a window that owns the user-control that the command is associated with.